# How do I get a header and two buttons to align properly to a border?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to coding, a friend and I are trying to put a website together and for the heading of the website, I'm having some issues getting the header to align to the border. I used `float:right` to make both the buttons align to the right side of the page. At that point they were kind of stuck in the middle of the border and I was stuck. I tried to move them away from each other with a `&nbsp` and that managed to get them both on the border but now the header is floating very high above the border and I want it to sit parallel to the buttons and on the border. Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom-style: ridge;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#login {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#register {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Title
 <form method="post">
 <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" id="login"> &nbsp
 <input name="register" type="submit" value="Register" id="register"></h1>
```

Is it possible to get these three elements to sit on the border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to create header tag with h1 and form in it than to insert form into h1 tag. Try this snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <style>
        header {
            border-bottom: 5px solid white;
            border-bottom-style: ridge;
            height: 50px;
        }
        h1 {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family:Helvetica;
            font-weight: bolder;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 50px;
        }
        .form {            
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            float: right;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 50px;
        }
        #login {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        #register {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <form class="form" method="post">
            <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" id="login">
            <input name="register" type="submit" value="Register" id="register">
        </form>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How were you able to get the buttons to display in the proper order and separated from each other, rather than in one block as they were for me?

Comment: Because I didn't use float:right on buttons (when you use float:right on multiple elements they will be on right but in revers order from your HTML order) instead I used it on whole form.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id name `#form` to the form tag and style as follows

```
#form{
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
}
```

Snippet below

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<style>
  h1 {
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    border-bottom-style: ridge;
  }
  h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
  #login {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
  }
  #register {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
  }
  #form{
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
}
</style>

<body>
  <h1>Title
<form method="post" id="form">
<input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" id="login"> &nbsp
<input name="register" type="submit" value="Register" id="register"></h1>
</body>

</html>
```